# Exclamation point at greeting

Tags: meaning-in-context, punctuation, greetings

Question:
What is the context of the structure "Hi name!" ?

Some time ago, I saw this, and after some research, I found out that this is grammatically valid [Exclamation point in a greeting](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/261847/exclamation-point-in-a-greeting).

But I've not found out in what context it is appropriate to use. How will a recipient think of such a greeting?

Comment: "Yeah, but a greeting is this: Hi John! You can use it in writing to your friends, for example. You can use it in dialogue for emphasis.

Comment: What do you mean "grammatically"? Grammar has nothing to do with this. Grammar is syntax and morphology. It's about fitting together different pieces of words into a word and about fitting together different words into larger syntactic structures. Grammar has nothing to do with spelling. Grammar has nothing to with spacing. Grammar has nothing to do with punctuation, with fonts, or with colors. That's because **grammar has nothing to do with writing.** Grammar is not just anything your teacher does not like.

Comment: First, if you're writing, you don't write _Hi_ any more. You write _Hey_. Second, if you **say** _Hi_, you're talking, not writing, so there's no exclamation point.

Comment: @tchrist With grammatically I meant that the syntax of the sentence does not violate any rules of punctuation. (Unfortunately, I got no English teacher anymore, but I need to improve my english... )

Comment: Punctuation is about writing, not about grammar.  Spelling or punctuating something the way people expect you to is not about grammar. Saying something the way people expect you to, in contrast, certainly can be.

Answer (score 1):

The only use that comes to mind is in emails.

For example:

> Hi Jack!
>
> I'm happy to help you out. Just forward me the details, and I can get it done by this evening

Note that this usage is only appropriate when you are reasonably familiar with the recipient, and is usually used by the individual responding to an email.

When in doubt, I wouldn't use this greeting, since it can come off as rude or unprofessional if used with someone of a higher status / with more authority. For example, using it in your first email with a prospective employer may be seen as unprofessional.

[Indeed.com](https://ca.indeed.com/career-advice/career-development/email-greetings) describes this greeting as being

> most commonly used to start an email because it's direct, polite and personal.

Comment: If it's polite, how can it be rude? Pollyanna, maybe.